# Get domain name of website where my remote js is included

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a script which I can include in any page on a same domain or on a different domain.
from that script, I am making ajax calls to my server. 
What I want is to get the domain name of the page where the script is included.
This is my code:

My script on a page say www.abc.com/index.html

```
<Script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.xyz.com/content/OScript.js" ></script>
```

My ajax call will go to a .ashx handler say

> http://demo.xyz.com/web/myHandler.ashx.

Inside that handler, if a access,

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

I get

> "demo.xyz.com" instead "www.abc.com"

I want to retrieve "www.abc.com" on server side.

I don't want to include/or send this domain name to server side via js.

Comment: Possibly [HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx). Not sure if it works with AJAX requests, but it's worth testing. Otherwise, you might have to pass the info back from the JavaScript itself with the [location object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)

Comment: yes `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer` is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HeaderReferer` value of the [HttpWorkerRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can help, like this:

Inside of your HTTP Handler code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var theProvider = (IServiceProvider)context;
    var theWorker = (HttpWorkerRequest)theProvider.GetService(typeof(HttpWorkerRequest));
    string theReferer = theWorker.GetKnownRequestHeader(HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderReferer);

    // Do something with referer here

}
```